# view customer whatsapp conversations - twilio

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to view whatsapp twilio conversations?

right now i use twilio to send whatsapp notifications to my clients

some of them respond to notifications, I would like to be able to see their responses, is it possible to view the chats?

Answer (score 2):

You can view the messaging logs from the Twilio Console, under Monitor > Logs > Messaging.

Comment: not what i describe

Comment: I’m what way? Please elaborate.

Comment: Probably through Conversations API you may implement what you need. Only need the token and the `conversation_id` to fetch all messages of it:  https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-message-resource